# Wolfram Elementary Cellular Automata Using Processing

Tags: java, processing, cellular-automata

I'm using a piece of code taken from the website The Nature of Code - https://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-7-cellular-automata/ - the portion I used was from example 7.1. I'm trying to create a one-dimensional cellular automaton using the Processing IDE, but I keep getting an error saying that brackets are missing from particular locations.

Errors:
-Missing curlry bracket "}", line 32
-Syntax error on "}", delete this, line 40

I've gone over it multiple times, but I can't see how this is wrong. Though I did try changing them as it says, only to get more errors. I thought maybe they were just in the wrong place, but I also can't see how that's the case. They seem to be correct as far as I can tell, but maybe I'm missing something. This is my first time using Processing, and it's been a long time since I last used Java. So maybe I'm mistaken.

```
class CA {
  int[] cells;
  int[] ruleset;
  int w = 10;
  // The CA should keep track of how
  // many generations.
  int generation = 0;
  CA() {
    cells = new int[width/w];
    ruleset = new int[]{0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0};
    cells[cells.length/2] = 1;
  }

  // Function to compute the next generation
  void generate() {
    int[] nextgen = new int[cells.length];
    for (int i = 1; i < cells.length-1; i++) {
      int left   = cells[i-1];
      int me     = cells[i];
      int right  = cells[i+1];
      nextgen[i] = rules(left, me, right);
    }
    cells = nextgen;
    // Increment the generation counter.
    generation++;
  }

  int rules(int a, int b, int c) {
    String s = "" + a + b + c;
    int index = Integer.parseInt(s,2);
    return ruleset[index];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    if (cells[i] == 1) fill(0);
    else               fill(255);
    // Set the y-location according to the generation.
    rect(i*w, generation*w, w, w);
  }
}
```

The program is supposed to print each generation of the one-dimensional CA on top of the next.

Comment: Do you maybe need to have that for loop on line 34 within a method? Also, put curly braces on lines 35, after the '(cells[i] == 1)' and after the else.

Comment: Curly braces around single-command code blocks such as the `fill(0);` and `fill(2555);` are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The for-loop in the end of the `CA` class is not supposed to be there. That is why you get the error: the parser expects either a method declaration or the end of the class, hence a curly bracket.

It looks like this loop is actually drawing the `CA` state, so you can try to wrap it in a `void draw(){}` method. Then it should be syntactically correct, not sure though whether it works as expected. Alternatively move the for-loop outside of the class and call `fill` based on the the `cells` state of an instance of the `CA` class.

In any case, will need some additional code that creates the `CA` instance and invokes the `generate` function.

Comment: Taking out the for-loop gets rid of the error. Thank you for your help!